# Como desenvolver um mecanismo assíncrono para testar pings?

Tags: c#, webforms, async

Estou com um problema de lentidão em uma transação que costuma realizar pings para verificar se determinados IP's estão acessíveis. Acontece que esta transação testa mais de 20 IP's diferentes, o que faz com que o tempo total da transação seja de 2 minutos. Para diminuir o tempo total desta transação, tentei implementar métodos assíncronos para testar estes IP's simultaneamente, mas não obtive êxito. Segue abaixo código implementado até o momento.

```
    public async Task<List<Foo>> Testar(List<Foo> lista)
    {
        Task<Foo>[] teste = new Task<Foo>[lista.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
        {
            teste[i] = Verificar(lista[i].IP);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
        {
            lista[i].Status = await teste[i];
        }

        return lista;
    }

    public async Task<Status> Verificar(string ip)
    {
    int retorno = await TestarIP(ip);
    return ((Status)retorno); 
    }


    public async Task<int> TestarIP(string ip)
    {            
        if(new Ping().Send(ip, timeOutPing).Status.Equals(IPStatus.Success))
            return 1;
        else 
            return 2;
    }
```

O código é executado assim que a página carrega (no onLoad), mas mesmo utilizando o Async/Await, está tendo o mesmo tempo de execução de anteriormente. Então, como posso criar threads para testar estes ip's simultaneamente?

Answer (score 3):

Quando você utiliza o "await" você está falando para o Main Thread sincronizar com seu método async, ou seja, ele vai esperar o resultado, resultando no tempo de execução igual ao anterior.

Você precisa criar um array com tasks e utilizar o método Task.WaitAll(tasks), assim elas serão executadas em paralelo.

Observação: Não confunda async com execução em paralelo.

Comment: Diego, você poderia postar um exemplo de código utilizando Task.WaitAll(tasks)? Enquanto isto, tentarei implementar conforme você indicou...